# Получить полное содержимое XML узла в виде текста

Tags: c#, xml, xpath, xmlparser

Есть такой фрагмент XML. Мне нужно получить содержимое тэта `<t_ns:request>` полностью с переносами и пробелами как есть.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1251"?>
<t_ns:gate xmlns:t_ns="http://ns/request">
  <t_ns:request>
    <t_ns:oper>test</t_ns:oper>
    <t_ns:id>12345</t_ns:id>
  </t_ns:request>
</t_ns:gate>
```

Получаю содержимое:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load("test.xml");
var ns = new XmlNamespaceManager(new NameTable());
ns.AddNamespace("t_ns", "http://ns/request");
XmlNode node = doc.SelectSingleNode("/t_ns:gate/t_ns:request", ns);
string value = node.InnerText;
```

Результат (неправильный):

```
<t_ns:oper xmlns:t_ns="http://ns/request">test</t_ns:oper>
<t_ns:id xmlns:t_ns="http://ns/request">12345</t_ns:id>
```

В результате свойство `InnerXml` возвращает текст и  автоматически добавляется пространство имен, а так же нет никаких переносов и пробелов. 
Свойство `InnerText` тоже не подходит, т.к. оно возвращает только значения дочерних элементов.

---

Прошу прощения, если не правильно описал проблему. Мне нужно получить только внутреннее содержимое тэга request без самого тэга request со всеми переносами и пробелами.

Результат, который хочу получить (кавычки добавлены, чтобы показать наличие переносов строк и пробелов):

```
'
    <t_ns:oper>test</t_ns:oper>
    <t_ns:id>12345</t_ns:id>
  '
```

Все это мне нужно для того, чтобы зашифровать эти данные как есть, а затем отправить вместе со всем ответом на удаленный сервер. На сервере расшифруют, сверят и, если хотя бы одного пробела не хватает, запрос будет считаться ошибочным. Такие вот требования от сервера(сервер сторонний).

Comment: Не надо извинений, не надо жирного текста! Вместо этого приведите _точный_ пример того, что должно получиться в итоге. С пометкой "Результат" вы привели то, что получается сейчас. Так приведите еще то, что нужно!

Comment: @AlexeyIvanov - Так-то понятно уже, что вы хотите. Однако, вы требуете невозможного. А, я вам фамилию неправильную написал? Вот и вы хотите тоже сделать с элементами xml. Учите xml, читайте про пространства имен.

Comment: Спасибо  за дополнения!

Comment: Как будет валидироваться запрос? Если по XSD, то на пространства имен можно не обращать внимание, мешать они не будут.

Comment: Содержимое в виде строки подписывается и подпись передается в отдельном тэге, на другой стороне открытые полученные данные так же в виде строки подписываются открытым ключом и две подписи сравниваются(это если кратко).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Извратиться можно с помощью ручного разбора, используя потоковый `XmlReader`.

В процессе чтения пробельные узлы (`XmlNodeType.Whitespace`) ещё существуют, поэтому их значения можно прочитать.

```
string value = null;
var ns = "http://ns/request";

using (var xmlReader = XmlReader.Create("test.xml"))
{
    xmlReader.ReadToFollowing("request", ns);

    using (var innerReader = xmlReader.ReadSubtree())
    {
        while (innerReader.Read())
        {
            value += innerReader.Value;
        }
    }
}
```

Этот код выдаёт следующий текст (кавычки добавлены для понимания):

```
'
    test
    12345
  '
```

В ходе дальнейшего разбирательства в комментариях выяснилось, что нужно сохранить теги, причём без указания пространcтва имён. Это приводит к тому, что получается невалидный xml. В целом я не верю, что на сервере требуют шифровать данные именно в таком виде. Я бы на вашем месте связался с техподдержкой сервера и уточнил, в каком именно виде нужно извлечь данные.

---

Объясняю. В показанном xml, например, нет узла с именем `oper`. Там даже нет узла с именем `<t_ns:oper>`. Зато есть узел `{http://ns/request}oper` - именно это его полное название, так сказать, фамилия и имя. `t_ns` - это всего лишь префикс и он может быть **любым**.

Согласно спецификации xml, все эти узлы одинаковы:

```
<t_ns:oper xmlns:t_ns="http://ns/request">test</t_ns:oper>
<a:oper xmlns:a="http://ns/request">test</a:oper>
<LongPrefix:oper xmlns:LongPrefix="http://ns/request">test</LongPrefix:oper>
<oper xmlns="http://ns/request">test</oper>
```

Также абсолютно одинаковы следующие xml:

```
<root xmlns:t_ns="http://ns/request">
  <t_ns:oper>test</t_ns:oper>
</root>
```

```
<root>
  <t_ns:oper xmlns:t_ns="http://ns/request">test</t_ns:oper>
</root>
```

Место объявления пространства имён не имеет значения. Главное - оно должно быть в видимом контексте. В первом случае неймспейс объявлен уровнем выше, хотя сам элемент `root` его не использует, но его видит элемент `oper`. Во втором случае неймспейс объявлен непосредственно в самом элементе.

Любой xml-парсер обязан понимать все эти виды записи. И что более важно, xml-райтеры (writer) имеют право записывать (создавать) документ в любом виде. Главное, чтобы он соответствовал спецификации xml.

Поэтому, повторюсь, **нельзя** закладываться в своём коде на форматирование документа.

Answer (score 0):

Если нужно только красиво показать текст, с отступами и т.д., тогда можно воспользоваться LiNQ2XML и классами `XDocument` и/или `XElement`. Для меня оказалось приятной неожиданностью, что у них метод `ToString` переопределен так, что возвращает форматированное представление текста. Исходное форматирование теряется, но выходной формат содержит переносы и стандартные отступы в 2 пробела для вложенных элементов.

Код:

```
string xml1 = @"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""windows-1251""?>" +
              @"<t_ns:gate xmlns:t_ns=""http://ns/request"">" +
               "  <t_ns:request>" +
               "      <t_ns:oper>test</t_ns:oper>" +
               "       <t_ns:id>12345</t_ns:id>" +
               "    </t_ns:request>" +
               "</t_ns:gate>";

XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xml1);
Console.WriteLine(doc.Root.Element(XName.Get("request", "http://ns/request")).ToString());
```

Вывод:

```
<t_ns:request xmlns:t_ns="http://ns/request">
  <t_ns:oper>test</t_ns:oper>
  <t_ns:id>12345</t_ns:id>
</t_ns:request>
```

Я специально исказил исходное форматирование для наглядной демонстрации разницы.

Comment: Спасибо. Проблема в том, что мне нужно получить внутреннее содержимое тэга request, тоесть:
<t_ns:oper>test</t_ns:oper>
  <t_ns:id>12345</t_ns:id>

а это на мой взгляд очень проблематично

Comment: @AlexeyFilyaev тогда я не могу понять зачем вам сохранять форматирование. Попробуйте более подробно описать цели и задачи, а то гадание получается. Ну либо воспользуйтесь ответом выше, там не важно что именно вы будете получать.

Comment: Для того, чтобы зашифровать эти данные как есть, а затем отправить вместе со всем ответом. На сервере расшифруют, сверят и, если хотя бы одного пробела не хватает, запрос будет считаться ошибочным. Такие вот требования от сервера(сервер сторонний).

Comment: @AlexeyFilyaev добавьте это уточнение в вопрос, это очень важная информация. Ну и в таком случае вам должно подойти решение  Александра.

Comment: К сожалению метод не помог, т.к. он возвращает только значения тэгов, а если же в методе xmlReader.ReadToFollowing("request", ns) прописать XPath, то автоматически добавляются пространства имен к каждому тэгу.

Comment: @AlexeyFilyaev в таком случае остается только работа напрямую с текстом. Вообще условия странные, это как нужно было извратиться, чтобы такое намудрить. Я работал и с подписанными, с шифрованными запросами, везде была важна только структура XML, остальное не имеет особого значения, так как после расшифровки или проверки подписи XML грузится в модель и больше исходный текст ни кого не интересует.

Comment: Даже если пробелы были бы не важны, то в любом случае мне нужно взять внутреннее содержимое тэга <request>( а это  2 внутренних тэга), сформировать из них строку, которую я подписываю и отправляю, а на том конце это проверяют и, если хотя бы один символ будет лишний, то хэш уже будет не тот, а в моем случае добавляются аж целая куча символов в виде пространства имен. Даже если я сформирую тэг с пространствами имен, то с того конца мне все равно придет XML без пространства имен и будет тоже самое.